# Where can I find my inetd.conf or xinetd.conf?

Tags: inetd

I tried looking into the `/etc/` folder, but I couldn't find it. I even did a full system scan using

```
find / -name inetd.conf
```

still in vain.

Comment: Have you installed either `xinetd` or `inetd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the inetd man page

```
 Upon execution, inetd reads its configuration information from a
 configuration file which, by default, is /etc/inetd.conf.
```

If it's not there, create it there as it's the default.

and next time you look for something use `locate inetd`